# Avoiding repeats while printing 'n' int

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print only products of 3 and 5 if x < 1000. I'm getting a lot of repeats. How do I make sure that I don't have any repeats?

```
for x in range(1000): 
    y = 3 
    z = 5 
    a = x % y 
    b = x % z 

    if a == 0: 
        print (x) 
    if b == 0: 
        print (y)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make an edit and place your code inside your question.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question.  How does the `x` relate the products 3 and 5?  Some sort of factor?

Comment: your getting lots of repeats of `3` because you never update `y`'s value. remove the last `if` clause

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the two conditions with disjunction (or):

```
for x in range(1000): 
    y = 3 
    z = 5 
    a = x % y 
    b = x % z     
    if a == 0 or b == 0: 
        print (x)
```